# React: Como realizar FETCH cada vez que la data cambie?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, useeffect

Buenas tardes comunidad,

Tengo una duda, estoy realizando una llamada FETCH desde el front de mi aplicación para obtener la data del usuario. Necesito que cada vez que actualice la información a través de un formulario, realice una solicitud GET para traer la data actualizada. Actualmente lo tengo con un setInterval, pero genera constantes e innecesarias solicitudes. He averiguado por muchas partes pero no puedo encontrar la forma de solucionarlo.

Este es el componente donde tengo el GET:

```
const UseFetchGetProfile = () => {

    const [profile, setProfile] = useState([]);
    const endpoint = "http://192.168.100.2:7000/user/profile/id";
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    const fetchData = async () => {

        const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            },
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setProfile(data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            fetchData()
        }, 5000)


        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, []);

    return { profile };
};

export default UseFetchGetProfile;
```

Y aquí es donde muestro la data y hago la solicitud POST a través de un formulario:

```
const UpdateDescription = () => {

    const { profile } = UseFetchGetProfile();

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [descripcion, setDescripcion] = useState()
    const toastS = useRef(null);
    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    setTimeout(() => {
        setShow(true)

        setData(profile)
    }, 1000);


    const formDescription = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const des = descripcion;
        const iduser = window.localStorage.getItem("IDUSER");

        fetch("http://192.168.100.2:7000/user/edit/profile/description", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: iduser,
                description: des,
            })
        }).then(x => x.json()).then(x => { console.log(x); toastS.current.clear(); FETCH_RESPONSE(x.message) });
    }

    const FETCH_RESPONSE = (x) => {
        const opcion = x;

        if (opcion === 'Ocurrio un error') {
            return toastS.current.show({ severity: 'error', summary: `${x}`, sticky: true, closable: true });
        } else if (opcion === 'Datos eliminados' || opcion === 'Datos guardados' || opcion === 'Datos actualizados') {
            return toastS.current.show({ severity: 'success', summary: `${x}`, sticky: true, closable: true });
        } else {
            return toastS.current.show({ severity: 'info', summary: `${x}`, sticky: true, closable: true });
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            {show ?
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={formDescription}>
                        <div className=''>

                            <div className="flex flex-col">
                                <p className='mb-2 mt-8 font-semibold'>Descripción personal (máx. 256 caracteres)</p>
                                <InputTextarea placeholder={data.description === '0' ? 'No posee descripción' : data.description} className='lg:w-3/4' maxlength={256} rows={4} cols={100} onChange={(e) => setDescripcion(e.target.value)} />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <button className='mt-5 p-3 text-white cursor-pointer w-42' type='submit'>Actualizar descripción</button>
                    </form>

                    <Toast ref={toastS} position="top-right" />

                </div> : null
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default UpdateDescription
```

Comment: Cuando dices `Necesito que cada vez que actualice la información a través de un formulario, realice una solicitud GET para traer la data actualizada` Te refieres a que cada vez que el usuario haga un submit del form, vuelvas a traer los datos recien guardados en la API?

Comment: @AndresGardiol exactamente a eso me refiero

Comment: Si estás actualizando la data desde un formulario dentro de la aplicación, creo que basta con hacer el fetch una vez el post haya terminado. Si lo que quieres es que el back-end notifique a la aplicación que los datos hayan cambiado en la base de datos, entonces, tienes que utilizar uno de los siguientes, o implementar el tuyo propio: SignalR, Pusher. MQTT. RabbitMQ. WebRTC. GRPC.

Comment: Como dice @Arriel puedes hacer el fetch luego de hacer el post. Otra forma sería tener como dependencia de tu custom hook el state que contiene la información del Form --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262515/how-to-handle-dependencies-array-for-custom-hooks-in-react

Comment: O si tienes acceso al backend, lo ideal saría que la misma llamada al POST te actualizara los datos y te retornara los datos actualizados, para que no tuvieras que hacer un doble llamado.